# formula to calculate variance on a single pivot table column

Tags: pivot, pivot-table

Is it possible when pivoting a series of data to calculate the difference between 2 columns when 1 column is your column filter? for example, I'm trying to compare 2 accounts receivable reports a week apart, so I inserted a manual column in both reports called "week" and then, before pivoting, I consolidated the 2 reports. Now I have 1 column called "week" with 2 different values. When I pivot, I want to put the "week" column in the Column Filter and I want to put the outstanding balance in values, and I then I need to calculate the difference between the weeks. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you working in Excel? You should tag your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MS Excel ...

From your description, I believe you have a raw data table that looks like this ...

[image]

... and a PivotTable that looks like this ...

[image]

If you were looking to calculate the difference between Account1 and Account2 on a weekly basis, this would be straight forward, using a calculated field. However, in order to calculate the change in Account 1 week over week, and the change in Account 2 week over week, you will need to go back to the raw data table and perform the calculation there, in new columns.

In the raw data, Column A is Week, Column B is Account1, and Column C is Account2 ...

1. Make header in Column D `Acc1WkChng` and the header in Column E `Acc2WkChng`
2. The first row of each of these columns is 0. The second row of `Acc1WkChng` is `=B3-B2`. The second row of `Acc2WkChng` is `=C3-C2`

The raw data table now looks like this ...

[image]

3. On the PivotTable, pick the PivotTable Tools -> Analyze Ribbon. Choose Change Data Source and increase the selected range to include Columns D and E.
4. Add Acc1WkChng and Acc2WkChng to the Values area. Format accordingly.

The PivotTable now looks like this ...

[image]

Note: This pivot table is merely a transpose of the original data. Presumably, you want to do something more interesting with it.